# Issue moving Local from Appdata to new drive (Windows 11)

Tags: windows, windows-11, appdata

As suggested in this [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/user-appdata-folder-taking-up-too-much-space/bd03f308-ce03-4c53-b18b-1e9fa07e3a70) forum, I wanted to move `Appdata/Local`, `Appdata/LocalLow` and `Appdata/Roaming` to my D: drive by right clicking and going to Proprieties/Location and use the built in method to move the folders.

I first tried with `Roaming`(I right clicked to get to proprieties and then clicked on Location, and changed Roaming location from there) and everything worked fine but now the Location option disappeared for the other folders (If I go to proprieties of other folders they don't show the option to move to another location).

On top of that runnig %appdata% leads me to the new location of `Roaming` and not to the actual`Appdata` folder anymore.
Can somebody help me understand what happened ? How can I move `Local` and `LocalLow`to the same location as Roaming?

Other notes:

- A `Roaming` folder still exists in the original location.
- I can not move roaming back becouse for some reason is now larger than it was before, and I don't have sufficient space on the drive to move it back.

Comment: Don’t use %AppData% to navigate Instead show hidden files and navigate to the old location. I am confused by what your actual question is

Comment: I am aware of that, the issue is that %appdata% sending me to the wrong place means that something appened to the enviorement variables

Comment: You need to finish moving the other folders, once you do that and they are no longer actively being used, you can delete the old files.

Comment: I can not gust cut copy the other folders, and as explained in the question windows decide to stop offering me the option to move them from proprieties, so how should I move them?

Comment: I don´t really know what to answer here,since the need to move appdata  is coming from the fact that I can not upgrade my ssd.

Comment: @John - This SSD is likely non-replaceable I have seen it before.

Comment: @Indiano - Has the registry key for those other folders been updated.  You should be able to move them yourself.  Where does %LocalAppData% point you to?

Comment: @John - I haven’t made that suggestion and strongly disagree that’s even a valid recommendation to the author’s problem. It’s effectively the response from a doctor that’s says “stop lifting your shoulder” when you visit your doctor about shoulder pain.

Comment: %LocalAppData% poits to the correct/standard Location (C:/user/username/appdata)

Comment: @John- I agree whit Ramhound that your suggestion is out of place. Throwing away a laptop( in my case ) to wich I can not make upgrasades (due to warranty restricxtions) really does not seem the the way to go here. Also there is an economical component to it, sometimes getting hacky is needed when i can not blast $300 on a new SSD (+ mounting services since I can not open it my self)

Comment: My solution is to boot into another (admin) profile, move the folder(s), then junction them back to the initial location.  This prevents me from needing to rely on the code that manages "moving stuff".

Comment: would also be an option, I am just scared of what windows did by itself since I used its utility to move Roaming,do you think is still fine to procedde like this?